# ¿Cómo crear un DropDown de Bootstrap con Razor?

Tags: bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC 5, ¿Cómo puedo cargar de datos un DropDown de Bootstrap?

Muestro código de cómo lo hago con Razor y cómo deseo cargarlo el otro

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DocumentoIdentidad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("myDropDown", (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaProveedores)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DocumentoIdentidad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Y también, ¿Cómo poner id a primer combo?

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta ayudó a completar la pregunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar este método para cargar DropDownList:

***ViewModel:***

```
public class ViewModel
{  
    //... tus otras propiedades 

    public int LabId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Labs { get; set; }       
}
```

***Controller:***

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // Cargar DropDownList obligar valores
    var model = new ViewModel
    {
        // Ejempleo I : Cargar desde una lista estática
        var model = new ViewModel();
        model.Labs = new List<SelectListItem> {
            new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text="One" },
            new SelectListItem { Value ="2", Text="Two" }
        };
        //

        //Ejempleo II : Cargar desde una base de datos   
        Labs = repository.Labs.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        })
    };
    return PartialView("Create", model);
}
```

***View:***

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LabId, new SelectList(Model.Labs, "Value", "Text"), "Select")
```

Espero que esto ayude...

Answer (score 0):

Deberias usar la lista del modelo y asignarla a tu dropdown. Por ejemplo tengo mi modelo Cuentas

> public List"<"Cuenta">" Cuentas { get; set; }
>
> public int CuentaOrigen { get; set; }

En el cual CuentaOrigen es el id de la cuenta, y Cuentas es la lista de cuentas.
El objeto Cuenta tendrá los campos value y text

> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CuentaOrigen, new
>   SelectList(Model.Cuentas, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new {
>   @class = "form-control" })

de esa forma la defines en cualquier dropdown.
Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

El Dropdown de Bootstrap necesita una lista para mostrar los elementos y no sirve un `<select>` de HTML que es lo que genera DropDownList.

Para eso, justo después de cerrar el `<button>` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    @foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaProveedores)
    {
        <li><a href="#">@item.Text @item.Value</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Esto hará que se muestre el desplegable con el texto y valor de los elementos del DropDown pero hay que trabajar un poco el Javascript, jugando con el `@item.Value` para que al hacer click en el elemento ocurra algo. Es más bonito pero más complejo de usar que un `<select>`.

Ah, y para poner el ID, sería mejor hacer:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DocumentoIdentidad, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaProveedores)
```